# jQuery Chosen plugin customization

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I am trying to use the [Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)
I am using select element options with .

I am using this for displaying timezone names by country names.
The country name as optgroup label and timezone name as options

My issues:

1. How to make the search work on optgroup labels also (not just on options)
2. How to change hover background color of option?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the highlighted class in chosen.css as below:

```
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted {
  background-color: #F26655;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #F26655), color-stop(90%, #2a62bc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F26655 20%, #F26655 90%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#F26655 20%, #F26655 90%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#F26655 20%, #F26655 90%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#F26655 20%, #F26655 90%); 
  color: #fff;
}
```

In my version this class was at line# 174.
For example #F26655 is your desired color.